# Click on "X" button to save file

Tags: c#

I am trying to make WTF application were user clicks on "X" button to make save file, now this can be done by Message.Show or to ask directly to save. I have created one code already but when user click on save or cancel, error window shows up thatprogram start working and it wants to send information to Microsoft.

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
   saveDlg.DefaultExt = ".rtf";
   saveDlg.Filter = "RTF Documents (.rtf)|*rtf";

   Nullable<bool> rezultat = saveDlg.ShowDialog();
   if (rezultat == true)
   {
      string filename = saveDlg.FileName;
      System.IO.File.Create(filename);
   }
   {
      this.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Making a `WTF` application sounds like a confusing and surly endeavor.

Comment: Close() itself triggers Closing event I believe. That is probably why it crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you might have intended there to be an `else`

```
else
{
    this.Close();
}
```

---

Secondly, calling `this.Close();` inside the `Window_Closing` event is just asking for a Stack Overflow exception.

You don't need to close the window again.  It is already closing.

Comment: Thank you, Sam I am, you are right. When I took out this.Close(); i was not getting any more error messages.

Answer (score 1):

modify with your code with proper else statement with your if condition

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        saveDlg.DefaultExt = ".rtf";
        saveDlg.Filter = "RTF Documents (.rtf)|*rtf";

        Nullable<bool> rezultat = saveDlg.ShowDialog();
        if (rezultat == true)
        {
            string filename = saveDlg.FileName;
            System.IO.File.Create(filename);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```